# I want to set a single int to a single variable but i am getting 2 int from 1 variable in php

Tags: php, string, integer, hex, rgb

Everyone

My issue is  want to set single string to a single variable but i am getting 2 strings from 1 variable in PHP

Here is my code I want to set a single int to a single variable.

```
include_once("colors.inc.php");

$ex=new GetMostCommonColors();
$path = '../functions/userProfiles/images/'.$imageName;
$colors=$ex->Get_Color( $path, $results, $brightness, $gradients, $delta);

foreach ( $colors as $hex => $count )
{
    if ( $count > 0 )
    {
        echo $hex;
    }
}
```

Output

> 00000 // First single int

> 60607 // second single int

Here is the output in the image
[image]

I just want this int to set in a single variable like this.

```
$int1 = first single int;
$int2 = second single int;
```

That's all how can I set a single int to a single variable.

Sorry for my bad English I am just confused.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Your question is hard to understand and I don't even know what to suggest that may make it better. Please update it with some better description, you can also show us your data, you'll display it with `var_dump($colors)`.

Comment: Whenever you start “numbering” inside your variable names, that is a pretty good indicator that you should probably be using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if i'm fully understand your question, but if you're trying to create variable names base off of the count you would do something like this

```
$index =0;
foreach ( $colors as $hex => $count )
{
    // Creating a name for the variable
    $variableName="Int$index";
    echo "\nVariableName: $variableName";

    // Assigning a value to that variable.
    $$variableName=$hex;
    echo "\n$variableName is: ".$$variableName;
    $index++;
}
echo "\n".$Int0;
echo "\n".$Int1;
```

The output should look something like this

```
VariableName: Int0
Int0 is: 00000
VariableName: Int1
Int1 is: 60607
00000
60607
```

If you're looking to get only one value from the method you called, the second parameter for Get_Color, should be set to 1 where $results is equal to the total number of results you want. I'm not too familiar with this method so I just did a quick web search to see what kind of value it takes and returns.

Comment: Thank you so much @SophiaKCruz your code worked. I really appreciate you.